# How can I correct elements of CSS styling not working on button

Tags: html, css

I'm learning to code and having some challenges I can't solve. I created a button on html and styled it with CSS but the styling is not taking effect. The properties for the button were created using CSS Button Creator.

```css
.btn {
    background: #11CDD4;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #11CDD4, #11999E);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #11CDD4, #11999E);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #11CDD4, #11999E);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #11CDD4, #11999E);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #11CDD4, #11999E);
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-me">
    <h2>Get In Touch</h2>
    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, non elit.</h3>
    <p class="contact-me">Love working with vibrant entrepreneurs so feel free to contact me.</p>
    <a class="btn" href="mailto:bashcele@email.com">CONTACT ME</a>
</div>
```

Comment: The image attached has the css code for the button

Comment: Image has not seen

Comment: Please show your CSS code along with your HTML. It's hard to see what is wrong when it is not there.

Comment: Im struggling to insert the css code but will try again

Comment: hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. How are you linking the CSS file to your HTML file? The CSS itself works fine.

Comment: I created a class called btn so on CSS its .btn {.........

Comment: Thanks Guys I will come back this once i get more comfortable on coding

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work just fine, i just copied your code...  do you have te css loaded or between -style- tags ?

```css
.btn {background: #11CDD4;background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #11CDD4, #11999E);background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #11CDD4, #11999E);background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #11CDD4, #11999E);background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #11CDD4, #11999E);background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #11CDD4, #11999E);}
```

```html
<div class="contact-me">
      <h2>Get In Touch</h2>
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, non elit.</h3>
      <p class="contact-me">Love working with vibrant entrepreneurs so feel free to contact me.</p>
      <a class="btn" href="mailto:bashcele@email.com">CONTACT ME</a>
 </div>
```